# AWS EC2 ssh connection closes after 10 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was able to properly access my EC2 instance till yesterday. I don't know what happened but suddenly today I am able to login to the instance but the server closes the connection after 10 seconds of login. What could be the reason?

The message I am getting

````
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-32-248 ~]$ Connection to ec2-18-221-152-137.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to ec2-18-221-152-137.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.```
````

Comment: What are your security group configuration? did you change the default security group?

Comment: Yes I did, I have added ssh,tcp and ICMP rules to be accessible from anywhere

Comment: This is a amazon linux ami right? not Ubuntu? If its ubuntu username = ubuntu, and if its amazon linux ami username = ec2-user

Comment: I have specified the user name correctly, Its ec2-user, I am using a amazon linux ami.

Comment: If you can successfully connect to the instance, but it then disconnects, this indicates that your network and security settings are correctly configured (otherwise you would not be able to connect). It might be caused by an unreliable network connection. Can you try it from another network (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone)?

Comment: @John Rotenstien thanks, that was the problem specifically.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simple, a stable internet connection is required to maintain the ssh connection as suggested by @John Rotenstien.